# how can i integrate google maps API for my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, ios4

I want to use Google Maps on my iPhone application.

I am finding it difficult to get the xml parser code for it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the mapKit Framework to your framework folder.

In your viewController.h file add code:-

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

In your viewController.m file:-

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication openURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London"]]
```

Comment: If you're going to rely on the internal Maps application to open a URL, why have the MapKit header import?

Answer (score 4):

The SDK includes the [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) framework. See this google [tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html) to get started.

Comment: but i want to use the google maps so that when i enter any state,it will take me to that place...i want to add a different functionality to it...

Comment: Then combine it with location services: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html